# How to fix an impossible Osmos level?

Tags: algorithm

I read this [optimisation problem](https://code.google.com/codejam/contest/2434486/dashboard#s=p0) in Google Code Jam. (The contest is over now, so it's okay to talk about.)

> Armin is playing Osmos, a physics-based puzzle game developed by Hemisphere Games. In this game, he plays a "mote", moving around and absorbing smaller motes.
>
> A "mote" in English is a small particle. In this game, it's a thing that absorbs (or is absorbed by) other things! The game in this problem has a similar idea to Osmos, but does not assume you have played the game.
>
> When Armin's mote absorbs a smaller mote, his mote becomes bigger by the smaller mote's size. Now that it's bigger, it might be able to absorb even more motes. For example: suppose Armin's mote has size 10, and there are other motes of sizes 9, 13 and 19. At the start, Armin's mote can only absorb the mote of size 9. When it absorbs that, it will have size 19. Then it can only absorb the mote of size 13. When it absorbs that, it'll have size 32. Now Armin's mote can absorb the last mote.
>
> Note that Armin's mote can absorb another mote if and only if the other mote is smaller. If the other mote is the same size as his, his mote can't absorb it.
>
> You are responsible for the program that creates motes for Armin to absorb. The program has already created some motes, of various sizes, and has created Armin's mote. Unfortunately, given his mote's size and the list of other motes, it's possible that there's no way for Armin's mote to absorb them all.
>
> You want to fix that. There are two kinds of operations you can perform, in any order, any number of times: you can add a mote of any positive integer size to the game, or you can remove any one of the existing motes. What is the minimum number of times you can perform those operations in order to make it possible for Armin's mote to absorb every other mote?
>
> For example, suppose Armin's mote is of size 10 and the other motes are of sizes [9, 20, 25, 100]. This game isn't currently solvable, but by adding a mote of size 3 and removing the mote of size 100, you can make it solvable in only 2 operations. The answer here is 2.

How to solve it? (Please explain in prose, rather than cryptic code)

---

I argued that "given a feasible solution that deletes a mote size x and adds a larger mote size y, there is a superior (at least as good) feasible solution for which all the motes added are smaller than all those deleted" (rather than delete the mote size x,  eat it after the larger mote size y)

That suggested a fast algorithm. Sort the motes from smallest to largest. Eat. If stuck, record 'delete the rest' as a potential solution. Add motes size `player - 1` until big enough to eat the mote we're stuck on. Repeat. Record the final 'additions only' solution. Choose the optimal solution among those recorded.

I implemented [this algorithm in Python](https://gist.github.com/matt-hickford/5531512#file-osmos-py). I'm fairly sure my code implemented my algorithm correctly. I guess my algorithm was wrong?

Comment: I don't know Python, so I don't know exactly how the functions you used work; the only things I can think of is that the queue sorting may give you descending order or that reading the input did something you didn't want it to. Everything else looks correct to me. Did you get any feedback? One possible optimization is that you can break early if (log (m/A)/log 2) + operations >= best_deletion_strategy because then you know you would have to add more motes than your best solution provides, and you can terminate.

Comment: Sounds like you've got the right idea, I did basically the same thing and got it right. Probably a "spot my error" question then. You may want to proceed to tag it with Python and paste the code into the question itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your problem is in the code:

```
# Let's add motes until we can eat it.
while A <= m:
  A += A-1
  operations += 1
```

This simulates adding more motes until you are large enough to eat the current one, but you then don't eat it.

In other words, I think you need to change this to:

```
while A <= m:
  A += A-1
  operations += 1
A+=m
```

to reflect growing when you eat the current one.

Comment: Oh. That's really simple and embarrassing. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Sort the motes from smallest to largest. Eat. If stuck add an extraMote sized `currentMoteSize - 1` until big enough to eat the mote we're stuck on. If the number of extraMotes added is >= the number of the remaining motes then return **the number of operations counted so far + the number of remaining modes**, else if the number of extraMotes added is >= the total number of motes then return **the total number of motes**, else eat the curent mote, add the number of extra motes added to the number of operations counted so far. Repeat until we have eaten all the motes. Return **the number of operations counted**.